# Exactly when is Math.random() seeded?

Tags: java, random, thread-safety

According to the documentation:

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> ```
> new java.util.Random
> ```
>
> This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.

I'm confused as to the scope of 'When this method is first called" - is it when *my* application first calls it? Is it only ever seeded once no matter what my application does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it is first called in your JVM (by any code).

It's doing an (unsafe - see link below) [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) of a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
private static Random randomNumberGenerator;
```

by calling:

```
private static synchronized void initRNG() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null) 
        randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}
```

**EDIT** Note that this code **is not** thread safe. Official bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6470700

Comment: -1 for not mentioning that this code isn't thread safe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Noob question, but can you just elaborate on the first sentence to explain what other apps would be using the same JVM?

Comment: @Andrew: Application / web app servers like Tomcat, JBoss or WebSphere allow to install several applications in the same VM.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla Gee... that's a little harsh. But sure - it was written pre-`volatile` keyword.

Comment: @Andrew Any code within your app or called by your app - maybe code within the JDK that is called deep down in some implementation that you're using.

Comment: @Bohemian: Sorry. The downvote was mainly because the unwary will think "this is the correct way to do lazy init" which is very dangerous.

Comment: So generally speaking it's when my app first directly or indirectly makes use of `Math.random()` - but not before my app starts?

Answer (score 2):

It's initialized when the method `Math.random()` is called for the first time.

Interestingly enough, in Java 5 and 6, the code uses the [broken double-checked-locking pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking), so it's *not* thread safe even though it looks like it is.

**[EDIT]** The correct code would look like this:

```
private static volatile Random randomNumberGenerator; // broken without volatile
```

or alternatively but more expensive:

```
public static synchronized double random() {
    ...
}
```

**[EDIT2]** Official bug: [Math.random() / Math.initRNG() uses "double checked locking"](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6470700)

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: Both of your statements are incorrect. The synchronized block doesn't prevent the reference to become non-null before the instance is completely initialized (so the next call can receive a half-working instance). And double checked locking is still a broken pattern in Java 7 according to Joshua Bloch who should know such things.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking for details. It would work if `randomNumberGenerator` was `volatile` (that's the fix in Java 5)

Comment: My bad, got things mixed up. +1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, the pertinent code for `Math.random()` is defined as:

```
private static Random randomNumberGenerator;

private static synchronized void initRNG() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null) 
        randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
}

public static double random() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null) initRNG();
    return randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
```

So, as `randomNumberGenerator` is a `static` variable, once it is initialised (the first call to `Math.random()`) by a call to it by any class in the JVM, it stays there (unless the class is no longer needed and unloaded.